# Как повысить эффективность алгоритма проверки чисел по гипотезе Коллатца?

Tags: python

Я написал такой код:

```
import time

mas = set()

def ThreeNPlusOne(n):
    while n > 1 and n not in mas:
        if n % 2 == 0:
            n //= 2
        else:
            n = 3 * n + 1
            n //= 2
        mas.add(n)
    return True

startTime = time.monotonic() #Начальное время

for i in range(1, 10**7):
    ThreeNPlusOne(i)
print("done.")

print(time.monotonic() - startTime) #Вычетаем из текущего времени начальное
```

Тут я использую множество и добавляю туда повторы, каждый раз проверяю наличие числа n в этом множестве, а можно ли как-нибудь ещё оптимизировать этот алгоритм на python?

Comment: Также при при умножении на 3 и добавлении 1 число в любом случае становится чётным, поэтому я сразу его делю на 2

Comment: Сколько времени занимает выполнение?

Comment: зависит от устройства, у меня примерно 8 секунд

Comment: а зачем вам вообще set и почему вы в каждом цикле заносите в него измененное n? а для ускорения кода можно попробовать lru_cache

Comment: Странно. У меня на телефоне 2 секунды, а на компе в три раза дольше :D Положите в сет сразу 1 и уберите проверку на n > 1

Comment: @strawdog сет нужен чтобы не проверять уже проверенные числа

Comment: Чётные можно не проверять.